# How to calculate the required sample size for x% accuracy?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, sample-size, confidence-interval

I've made an algorithm for parsing some strings, and the question I have is how many random strings should I collect and test to get an estimate of how good the algorithm is?

Testing on all is not possible as I would have to manually check 2 mill records.

Found some formulas and calculations online but don't know how or if they work for my case.

- http://www.surveysystem.com/sscalc.htm
- http://www.raosoft.com/samplesize.html

The distribution and confidence level is basically the factor that I don't know how to estimate, and I'm guessing I'm not the first or the only one.

The tests report with pass or fail.

Was also thinking to split the population (strings) in groups / patterns and calculate the margin of error for each and have a weighted score according to how many strings match each pattern.

Comment: Confidence levels aren't estimated: they are your *criteria* for the stringency of the test. To estimate the distribution, take a small sample!

Comment: @whuber but how will those account for the final accuracy. 
Let's say I have 100 random samples out of which 97 are correctly parsed what would be the margin of error? how can I tell the distribution for free typed strings? as they don't have a mesurable value.